# Link to http or https

Tags: html, http, https, hyperlink, href

While adding a hyperlink to another site (which has SSL), the site documentation sometimes say to link to the `http://` link instead of the `https://` (e.g. [Play store](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html), which is a site that uses SSL but it does not tell you to link to `https`; instead, it says to link to `http`). They do not matter (as they function normally), but would there be a reason to link to the `http://` instead the `https://`?

Comment: _“but would there be a reason to link to the `http://` instead the `https://`?”_ – yes: `s` key on keyboard broken.

Comment: Are you serious? SO is not a site for jokes.

Comment: It is also not a place for questions that can not be answered. HTF are _we_ supposed to know, what _someone else’s_ reasoning might be behind setting a link a certain way …?

Comment: I was talking about hyperlinks, as you do not even need a broken `s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe they don't want extra encryption and lowering down the site speed as SSL may decrease performance somewhat.

If users are downloading large, public files, there may be a system burden to encrypt these each time.

Some browsers may not support SSL.

You will probably want the home page accessible via HTTP, so that users don't have to remember to type https to get to it.

Your specific portion of page needs secure http(https) not whole site.

Your site is indexed mainly on http on Search engines.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. HTTP would be a better option to use in hyperlinks, and make the website themselves decide weather to use SSL or not then.